# Capturing the ESC key using JavaScript only

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I have a custom video play with it's own controls. I have a script to make changes to the controls when the user enters and exists full screen. The problem is that when I exit fulls creen using the `ESC` key instead of the button, the style changes to the controls are not reverted back. I need to ensure that exiting full screen using `ESC` or button will result in the same behaviour.

CSS:

```
function toggleFullScreen() {
  
  elem = document.getElementById("video_container");
  var db = document.getElementById("defaultBar"); 
  var ctrl = document.getElementById("controls");
  
  if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
      !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement) {  // current working methods
    if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
          
          ctrl.style.width = '50%';
          ctrl.style.left = '25%';
          full.firstChild.src = ('images/icons/unfull.png');
          elem.requestFullscreen();          
        } else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
          full.firstChild.src = 'images/icons/unfull.png';
          ctrl.style.width = '50%';
          ctrl.style.left = '25%';
          elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
          
          ctrl.style.width = '50%';
          ctrl.style.left = '25%';
          full.firstChild.src = 'images/icons/unfull.png';
          elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
          
        }
  } else if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        full.firstChild.src = 'images/icons/full.png';
        ctrl.style.width = '100%';
        ctrl.style.left = '0';        
        document.exitFullscreen();
        }
        else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        full.firstChild.src = 'images/icons/full.png';
        ctrl.style.width = '100%';
        ctrl.style.left = '0'; 
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        }
        else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
       
        ctrl.style.width = '100%';
        ctrl.style.left = '0';
        full.firstChild.src = 'images/icons/full.png';
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        } 
}
```

Comment: How does this question involve Java?

Comment: I thought the syntax may be similar enough for someone with Java experience to help. Sorry if I was wrong.

Comment: Yeah, you'll not want to make that assumption since while both languages' syntax share C language roots, the languages are otherwise completely different. Good luck with your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Edit:*** This answer is outdated.  For modern browsers, [@Gibolt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47614261/2012396) is better.  If you need to support IE11, you can fallback to the legacy event.keyCode.  See [this article](https://medium.com/@uistephen/keyboardevent-key-for-cross-browser-key-press-check-61dbad0a067a) for more details.

It sounds like you want to attach a keypress event to the document.  Something like this ought to do the trick.

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
        alert("Esc was pressed");
    }
};
```

For more info, check out [this article](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html)

Comment: do you think adding document.onkeypress.keycode==27 as an OR condition in the exit fullscreen statements would solve my problem?

Comment: note that `window.event` and `evt.keyCode` have been deprecated. Use `KeyboardEvent.key` as suggested by Gibolt below.

Answer (score 26):

## event.key === "Escape"

More recent and much cleaner: use `event.key`. No more arbitrary number codes!

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    const key = event.key; // Or const {key} = event; in ES6+
    if (key === "Escape") {
        // Do things
    }
});
```

#### Modern style, with lambda and destructuring

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", ({key}) => {
    if (key === "Escape") // Do things
})
```

[Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[Supported Browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=keyboardevent-key)

Comment: I'm curious why "`keypress`" event does not work but "`keydown`" does.

Comment: @Jarad this is how I came to find this, I was also trying to bind to keypress.